# Open "Go to Folder" keyboard shortcuts outside of Finder

Tags: osx-yosemite, hotkeys

Is there a shortcut key to launch "Go To Folder" when you're focused outside of Finder? I am using Yosemite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> is what you want. It works on the Desktop as well as Finder.

[image]

Source: [Mac Keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

---

A productive way to do this when in another application would be to use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to quickly move to Finder then use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open "Go to Folder".

Comment: Yes as long as I'm in the Desktop and don't have other open/front window. Is there any global hotkey?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, probably because it could conflict with a shortcut of the open application. I would suggest doing `Command + Tab` to quickly move to Finder then do `Command + Shift + G`. Faster than moving the mouse around. Not perfect but as productive as you can get without third party software.